# Head First C Google Map associated with JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, gps

This question is from the book Head First C by Griffiths. Starting on p. 110 the book instructs how to develop a JSON file that will be read by the map application on the website http://dogriffiths.github.io/HeadFirstC/map.html. Starting from a file containing the values of the latitude and longtitude in CSV format a C program is developed to convert it into a JSON file. Up to this point everything worked perfectly although I doubt whether the generated output file conform with the standard of JSON files due to my lack of knowledge.

The problems begin after the previous step. First of all, when I try to save the webpage as a whole (from Chrome, Firefox on  Ubuntu 12.04.3 32-bit and Windows 7 64-bit) the local copy of the map.html file is useless. When the file is double clicked a white blank page is displayed with no map to be seen. However, when it is saved with the only html file option the map is displayed but the JSON file in the same directory is not read by the program to display the corresponding red markers. What may be the reason behind this and how can I remedy the situation? It has been bugging me a lot these days.

Thanks in advance

The corresponding files are

"output.json"

```
data=[
{latitude: 42.363400, longitude: -71.098465, info: 'Speed = 21'},
{latitude: 42.363327, longitude: -71.097588, info: 'Speed = 23'},
{latitude: 42.363255, longitude: -71.096710, info: 'Speed = 17'},
{latitude: 42.363182, longitude: -71.095833, info: 'Speed = 22'},
{latitude: 42.363110, longitude: -71.094955, info: 'Speed = 14'},
{latitude: 42.363037, longitude: -71.094078, info: 'Speed = 16'},
{latitude: 42.362965, longitude: -71.093201, info: 'Speed = 18'},
{latitude: 42.362892, longitude: -71.092323, info: 'Speed = 22'},
{latitude: 42.362820, longitude: -71.091446, info: 'Speed = 17'},
{latitude: 42.362747, longitude: -71.090569, info: 'Speed = 23'},
{latitude: 42.362675, longitude: -71.089691, info: 'Speed = 14'},
{latitude: 42.362602, longitude: -71.088814, info: 'Speed = 19'},
{latitude: 42.362530, longitude: -71.087936, info: 'Speed = 16'},
{latitude: 42.362457, longitude: -71.087059, info: 'Speed = 16'},
{latitude: 42.362385, longitude: -71.086182, info: 'Speed = 21'}
]
```

"gpsdata.csv"

```
42.363400,-71.098465,Speed = 21
42.363327,-71.097588,Speed = 23
42.363255,-71.096710,Speed = 17
42.363182,-71.095833,Speed = 22
42.363110,-71.094955,Speed = 14
42.363037,-71.094078,Speed = 16
42.362965,-71.093201,Speed = 18
42.362892,-71.092323,Speed = 22
42.362820,-71.091446,Speed = 17
42.362747,-71.090569,Speed = 23
42.362675,-71.089691,Speed = 14
42.362602,-71.088814,Speed = 19
42.362530,-71.087936,Speed = 16
42.362457,-71.087059,Speed = 16
42.362385,-71.086182,Speed = 21
```

P.S. I have done exactly as told in the book and I am very unfamiliar with JS. 
The link for map.html has been updated, refer errata [https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920015482]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to install XAMPP and run the Apache server on your machine.

Be careful with the format of the data you have outputted through the C file because I found that many others have missed apostrophes, and `map.html` would not be able to parse it.

After placing both of the file i.e., `map.html` and `output.json` (be careful with the name as it is hardcoded), run it using the URL `http://localhost/gpsdata/map.html`. And don't forget to zoom in as it is looking like a point in the default condition.

You have to zoom it like six times and *voilà*: you will see the trace the cyclist has followed.

Answer (score 1):

Open O'Reilly map website.. Den click on settings ->tools->view source code..
Copy paste the code in notepad save it as map.HTML in same folder wer all other files are stored..
Double click on map.HTML and it will locate output.json file's information

Comment: I will try it when I have the time thanks for the answer. I assume that it worked for you.

Comment: Yes I see it again.. You have to open map.HTML in wamp server.. And change the input file i.e. spooky.CSV just change latitude longitudes.. Keep a difference of 1.. Den you can see clearly ur lat Lon. And zoom it play it

Answer (score 1):

OS : Ubuntu 14.04
Browser : Mozilla
I had the same problem as you but now, I found the EXACT solution. So what I did :

1- I installed Apache Server. (Actually I already had it on ubuntu)

2- Opened http://oreillyhfc.appspot.com/map.html and ctrl+s and saved as "All Files" (Not "Web Page, Completely") to my geo2json project folder.

3- I move geo2json project folder to localhost. (Made like that : /var/www/html/geo2json/)

---Don't forget to be root to be able to move file => sudo -i

---Move command => mv geo2jsonFolderLocation /var/www/html

4- Then opened my browser (Mozilla) and linked localhost/geo2json/map.html

And it worked !